# How to add Date Picker In asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In Asp.net MVC 3 how do I add and use a DatePicker?

Comment: Did you tried it on your own first? Just google it up.

Comment: adding a date picker has nothing to do with razor, even with the aspx engine the method is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this kind of thing is to add an EditorTemplate for the type `DateTime`. You add a UserControl under  `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\`, set the `@model` to `DateTime` and have the view display whatever kind of date view/picker etc you want.

Then, when you use your `@Model.EditorFor()` it will correctly display the right view and bind the right value to your model.

[Lord Google](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net%20mvc%20date%20picker%20editor%20template) helped me find :
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4 (<< newer)
AND
http://www.nickharris.net/2010/08/asp-net-mvc-editor-template-for-jquery-datepicker/

Both articles describe how to add an EditorTemplate which uses the JqueryUI DateTimePicker

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#FFC0CB;color:#FF6347">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
model.Createddt, new { DateTime.Now, id="datepicker"})</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker").datapicker();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to add a date picker and I can't imagine any of them being significantly different to use with razor. A simple [search](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=datepicker%20mvc%20razor) yielded [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/13/developing-web-apps-using-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-and-ef-code-first-part-2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a textbox and then use jquery to make it a datepicker, here is a piece of code. Remember to reference the jquery & jquery UI js libraries to your project.

```
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
    </script>

@Html.TextBox("datepicker")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Creating A Helper Extension**
Now that we’ve created a working date picker, let’s put it into an extension method in order to clean up the UI & allow us to use it elsewhere.
Create a new folder in the root of the project, called ‘UI’, and create a new class called ‘HtmlHelperExtensions.cs’ in our new folder:

[image]

In the new class, add the following method to the class ( You’ll need to add a using clause to System.Web.MVC & System.Text ):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DatePickerHarness.UI
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {

     public static string DatePicker(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string imageUrl, object date)
        {
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            // Build our base input element
            html.Append("<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + name + "\" name=\"" + name + "\"");

            // Model Binding Support
            if (date != null)
            {
                string dateValue = String.Empty;

                if (date is DateTime? && ((DateTime)date) != DateTime.MinValue)
                    dateValue = ((DateTime)date).ToShortDateString();
                else if (date is DateTime && (DateTime)date != DateTime.MinValue)
                    dateValue = ((DateTime)date).ToShortDateString();
                else if (date is string)
                    dateValue = (string)date;

                html.Append(" value=\"" + dateValue + "\"");
            }

            // We're hard-coding the width here, a better option would be to pass in html attributes and reflect through them
            // here ( default to 75px width if no style attributes )
            html.Append(" style=\"width: 75px;\" />");

            // Now we call the datepicker function, passing in our options.  Again, a future enhancement would be to
            // pass in date options as a list of attributes ( min dates, day/month/year formats, etc. )
            html.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function() { $('#" + name + "').datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImage: '" + imageUrl + "', duration: 0 }); });</script>");

            return html.ToString();
        }
  }
  }
```

To add the namespace, open up your web.config ( you can either use the web.config in the ‘View’ folder, or go to the root and add it there ), and add the following into the namespaces element:

```
<add namespace="YourProjectNameGoesHere.UI"/>
```

Now that we’ve got that in there, we can access the extension method from within our view:

[image]

Now that we have the abillity to call our extension method, let’s make this a bit more exciting and wrap everything into a form that will post back to an action in our controller.  First we’ll need to add our complete form to the frontend:

```
<%= Html.DatePicker("Date", "/Content/images/calendar.gif", this.ViewData["TheDate"]) %>
```

[réferance url](http://codesprouts.com/post/Creating-A-DatePicker-Extension-In-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I created a UserControl and called it "DateTime" (DateTime.ascx) in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates add added this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%: Html.TextBox("",  String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.HasValue ? Model : DateTime.Today), new { @class = "dp"})%>
```

My View then looked like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
```

My script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".dp").datepicker();
});
```

These were the links I added to the view (in case you don't have them, you can find them using Nuget and type "jquery.ui"):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js") " type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet"/>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css")" type="text/css"/ rel="Stylesheet"/>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet"/>
```